# Excel Help, Sum most recent 52 weeks of info ignoring blanks

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have got 104 weeks of hours worked in a spreadsheet, in the expected order. Oldest on the left and most recent on the right.

I am trying to get the sum of the most recent 52 weeks in which hours have been worked, some weeks are blank. So I want to ignore that week, so far have only managed to get the first 52 weeks.

I tried to get reverse the formula I used previously but it didn't seem to work when testing it out

I looked in to it and tried this formula to begin with, just trialing it on one row. but its giving

```
=SUM(INDEX(C607:DB607, MATCH(TRUE, INDEX(C607:DB607<>"", 0), 0)):
  INDEX(C607:DB607, MATCH(TRUE, INDEX(C607:DB607<>"", 0), 0) + 51))
```

the tricky part seems to be ignoring blanks, I have found a solution that just counts a specified amount of cells back including blanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the most recent ones are to the right, it would look like this in Excel 365:

```
=SUM(TAKE(FILTER(C607:DB607,C607:DB607<>""),1,-52))
```

If you didn't have Excel 365, I think you would be looking at a monster like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IF(C607:DB607="",0,C607:DB607)*(MMULT(IF(C607:DB607="",0,1),IF(COLUMN(A1:INDEX(1:1,104))>=ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,104)),1,0))>COUNT(C607:DB607)-52))
```

Slightly shorter:

```
SUMPRODUCT(N(+C607:DB607)*(MMULT(IF(C607:DB607="",0,1),IF(COLUMN(A1:INDEX(1:1,104))>=ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,104)),1,0))>COUNT(C607:DB607)-52))
```

[image]

*Explanation of use of Mmult*

The purpose of mmult here is to take only the first element of an array, then the sum of the first two elements, three elements... up to 104.

Consider  applying it to an array with 10 elements. You have to construct an upper right triangular array with 10 X 10 elements.

Step 1

Use this part of the formula to place numbers 1..10 in a row array:

```
=COLUMN(A1:INDEX(1:1,10))
```

The expression inside the brackets defines a range from A1 to J1 and COLUMN gives a single-row array containing the column numbers of that range. The result is shown in A1..K1 below.

Step 2

Use this part of the formula to place numbers 1..10 in a column array:

```
=ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,10))
```

The expression inside the brackets defines a range from A1 to A10 and ROW gives a single-column array containing the row numbers of that range. The result is shown in A2..A11 below.

Step 3

Compare each pair of elements in the two arrays to generate a triangular array. If you compare a row array to a column array, Excel automatically generates a 2-dimensional array containing the results of each comparison e.g. 1<=1 for element (1,1) so you get a 1 in the first row and first column, but 2>1 for element (2,1) so you get a zero in the second row and first column.

The result looks like this:

[image]

Step 4

Use MMULT to multiply the values in your data (setting blank values to zero and non-blank values to 1) with the triangular matrix to get a rolling count of the non-blank values. Recall that in matrix multiplication, each element in the first (in this case the only) row of the first array is multiplied by each element in the first column of the second array to give the first element of the result, then each element in the first array is multiplied by each element in the second column of the second array to give the second element of the result and so on.

If you had some data with (say) 6 non-blanks and 4 blanks in M2:V2, using the formula

```
=MMULT(IF(M2:V2="",0,1),IF(COLUMN(A1:INDEX(1:1,10))>=ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,10)),1,0))
```

the result in M4:v4 would look like this

[image]

and you can just pick off the ones that you need e.g. for the last two, those where the last formula above gives 5 or 6.

Comment: Or a bit shorter would be to use TOROW with ignore blank parameter instead of filter: =SUM(TAKE(TOROW(C607:DB607,1),1,-52))

Comment: Agree. Actually I used a formula like this =LET(r,RANDBETWEEN(0,10),IF(r=0,"",r)) to generate some test data so they weren't 'proper' blanks but normally it would be shorter.

Comment: Tom Sharpe You offer a great solution and i try to understand your formula breking it into small pieces but this part is so hard to understand?Is not for the first time when i use mmult.Every time when i see solutions with mmult i become very curios.
This is the part which i don t understand and maybe if you have the time you will explain please-
IF(COLUMN(A1:INDEX(1:1,104))>=ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,104)),1,0)

Comment: Will add to my answer